How to handle an exception with streams
Lets face this snippet.
String txt = "this\nis\na\n\n\ntest\n";
Stream.of (txt.split ("\n")).filter (l -> l != null && l.isEmpty () == false && l.isBlank () == false)
    .forEach (l -> 
    {
        try
        {
            foo (l);
        }
        catch (Exception ignore)
        {
        }
    });



foo (String s) throws Exception
{ 
   // whatever 
}

Because foo is throwing an exception I need to enclose it inside the forEach with an exception-handler.The compile would bring an error (unhandled exception) if not.
2 questions

Is there any way I can make this "better looking"?
e.g. sort of
 Stream.of (...).filter (...).IgnoreException ().forEach (...)


Is did not find a way to handle an exception of foo outside of the stream.
e.g.
try
{
  Stream....forEach (l -> foo (l));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}

Any way of doing that?



BTW idea for "better looking": 1) use ! l.isEmpty() instead of l.isEmpty() == false; (same for l.isBlank() but see next point); 2) just ! l.isBlank() instead of ! l.isEmpty() && ! l.isBlank() (isBlank includes isEmpty - empty string is blank too); 3) filter(l -> l != null).filter(l -> ! l.isBlank) instead of filter(l -> l != null && ! l.isBlank()) 4) maybe
filter(Objects::nonNull) instead of filter(l -> l != null) (from previous point)

To add on user85421’s comment, split never produces null results, so the null test is entirely obsolete. Further, if you can’t come up with something better than forEach, your code is only a loop in disguise anyway. Then, using a loop in the first place is the “better looking” solution: for(String line: txt.split("\n")) { if(!line.isBlank()) foo(line); } Then, you can put the loop inside a try block or propagate the exception to the caller, which ins definitely the better option than swallowing exceptions.
